# Any Mobile Application For Checking SO sites?

Tags: discussion

I want to know whether there is any mobile application for SO sites. There are sites like stackmobile.com. But I need some SO mobile application that runs well on both Iphone and for other phones like Nokia.

Comment: *SCNR:* How about a browser? \*duck\*

Comment: @PaddedCell Well browser is good ;) But it will be really great if I get a separate app for SO :D isn't it?

Comment: Just checking, but you know there's a mobile site right?  Browse the site on your iPhone for instance, the rendering is adjusted specifically for mobile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are unlikely to be able to find the exact same application that works on different phone platforms, but there are individual apps out there. Also, any mobile phone application will only have read access right now, since the write API isn't there yet.

[Six to Eight](https://stackapps.com/questions/623/six-to-eight-an-iphone-client-now-in-the-app-store) is a very nice iPhone app for reading Stack Exchange. I'm not sure if there are any for Nokia phones, but you can browse [Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com) and see what you can find.

Comment: `...since the write API isn't there yet.` Do they plan on adding one? Last thing I heard they don't want to, because it could be to easily misused.

Comment: @PaddedCell Looks like it's [tentatively slated for v3](http://stackapps.com/questions/1999/announcing-api-version-1-1), though there are no specific release plans that I know of.